# WSServletContainerInitializer and SpringBeanAutowiringSupport

Tags: spring, jax-ws, tomcat7

I have some integration issues regarding the mentioned classes but only with "too new" tomcat versions.

The base setup:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="FooService" version="2.5" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>FooService</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jax-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

FooServiceImpl:

```
@WebService(serviceName = ServiceInfo.SERVICENAME, targetNamespace = ServiceInfo.TARGETNAMESPACE, endpointInterface = "bar.FooService")
@HandlerChain(file = "/handler-chain.xml")
public class FooServiceImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements FooService {

    @Autowired
    private Bar bar;

    << some methods using the injected bar singleton >>
```

JAX-WS dependency: compile 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.2.7'
Spring version: 3.1.2.RELEASE

With Tomcat 7.0.22 I don't have the problem. The declared webapp version in the web.xml is 2.5. Tomcat 7.0.22 doesn't process the WSServletContainerInitializer. So as declared in web.xml, ContextLoaderListener is initialized first, so an instance of Bar will be available in the WebApplicationContext. Then WSServletContextListener instantiates FooServiceImpl, aoutowiring works and everybody is happy.

But... My colleague tried it with Tomcat 7.0.30 and the autowiring didn't work (7.0.32 gives the same problem, currently this is the newest). It really couldn't work, because the new Tomcat version has processed WSServletContainerInitializer, not taking into account the 2.5 webapp version (and  metadata-complete="true").

I've found a possible solution. I commented out the body of the web.xml, changed webapp version to 3.0 and created a WebapplicationInitializer:

```
public class MyInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        ContextLoader loader = new ContextLoader();
        loader.initWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    }

}
```

This worked perfectly for me. But not for my colleague... If he tried to run the app, WSServletContainerInitializer fired first which created exactly the same wiring problem as above.

Obviously we can "hack" the problem getting rid of SpringBeanAutowiringSupport and inject Bar manually from a getter or a web method, or any similar way. But SpringBeanAutowiringSupport would be much clearer, so we would like to use it if there's a good solution for the above problems.

UPDATE: this causes the problems: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53619

Comment: Not sure about that bug being the culprit.Changelog http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html says it was fixed in 7.0.29. I am seeing the same behaviour with Tomcat 7.0.39

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for me the solution was to invoke the following when the autowired reference is null

```
processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

I hope it helps for all.